# Spark Cell magic not found

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I have python2 env. on windows 10 with jupyter notebook.

after following instructions in this tutorial I managed to install spark on windows 10: 
https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-spark-on-windows-pyspark-4498a5d8d66c

but when I try to run cell magic for SQL I get the following error :

> ERROR:root:Cell magic `%%sql` not found.

when I used %lsmagic I could not find sql cell magic among them.

also I noticed there was no option for pyspark kernel when starting new notebook in Jupyter.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use SQL or Spark-SQL? I've used [iPython-SQL](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql) which was great, and there's also [SparkMagic](https://github.com/jupyter-incubator/sparkmagic) which sounds like what you're looking for. Try installing SparkMagic, which does use `%%sql` magic.

Comment: I already installed both but still getting the same error message when trying to execute cell magic.

Comment: It might not be a good idea to have both installed, since they both use the `%%sql` for magic. Try uninstalling one of them.

Comment: I uninstalled iPython-SQL but still facing the same problem